# Dialog box does not inherit from the them in Angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, styles

Why dialog box does not inherit theme in angular material? I tried to add a dark theme to the styles file to fix this as I saw that as a solution but it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have included your theme in styles.css ( or styles.scss). Since the dialog is inside of a global overlay container, an additional step is required for those components to be affected by the theme's css class selector.

To do this, you can add the appropriate class to the global overlay container:

```
import {OverlayContainer} from '@angular/cdk/overlay';

@NgModule({
  // ...
})
export class UnicornCandyAppModule {
  constructor(overlayContainer: OverlayContainer) {
    overlayContainer.getContainerElement().classList.add('unicorn-dark-theme');
  }
}
```

Link to official documentation: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#multiple-themes

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it fixed on my app by adding the class.